# map multiple div elements into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Faced with mapping problem, it returns for me a blank array with two empty elements. Having a button where on click it gets related div block, then I'm trying to get type and number and push them into array. What I am doing wrong here?

```
<div class="chapter">
    <div class="span">
        <div class="contact">
            <span class="type">
                2
            </span>
            <span class="number">
                1111111111
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="contact">
            <span class="type">
                4
            </span>
            <span class="number">
                33333333333
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

function func(el) {
    let block = $(el).closest("div.chapter")
    let arr = $(block.find('.contact')).map(function () {
        let val = $(this).find('.type, .number').val();
        return val;
    }).get();

    console.log(arr) //result: ["", ""]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.val()`](https://api.jquery.com/val/) method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select and textarea. You need to use [`text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) method for this, as `text()` string containing the combined text of matched elements.

**Using `.val()` on `span` element:**

```js
console.log( $('.type').val() )
// Return empty string
console.log( typeof $('.type').val() )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="type">2</span>
```

**Using `.text()` on `span` element:**

```js
console.log( $('.type').text() )
// Returns '2'
console.log( typeof $('.type').text() )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="type">2</span>
```

Also call them individually for each element like this:

```
let arr = block.find('.contact').map(function() {
   let type = $(this).find('.type').text().trim();;
   let number = $(this).find('.number').text().trim();;
   return { type, number};
}).get();
```

This will return you array of objects, where each object has text content of `type` & `number` class elements.

**DEMO:**

```js
let arr = $('.span').find('.contact').map(function() {
   let type = $(this).find('.type').text().trim();
   let number = $(this).find('.number').text().trim();
   return { type, number};
}).get();

console.log( arr )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="span">
    <div class="contact">
        <span class="type">
            2
        </span>
        <span class="number">
            1111111111
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
        <span class="type">
            4
        </span>
        <span class="number">
            33333333333
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not match with the HTML markup you have provided. You can simply loop through all the element with class *contact* and find the element inside with specific *class* to from the object.

**Please Note:** The *span* element does not have the value property, you have to use [**`.text()`**](https://api.jquery.com/text/).

```js
function func() {
  let arr = $('.contact').map(function () {
    return  {
        type: +$(this).find('.type').text().trim(),   //find text and convert to number using +
        number: +$(this).find('.number').text().trim()//find text and convert to number using +
    }
  }).get();

  console.log(arr);
}
func();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="span">
    <div class="contact">
        <span class="type">
            2
        </span>
        <span class="number">
            1111111111
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="contact">
        <span class="type">
            4
        </span>
        <span class="number">
            33333333333
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use simple JavaScript it's easy!

```
document.querySelectorAll(".contact").forEach((elm)=>{
        arr=[] ;
        arr.push(elm.children[0].innerText);
        arr.push(elm.children[1].innerText);

        console.log(arr)
    })
```

Comment: The original post used `map()`, which I think was part of the point of the question.  Also, it looks like the `$(...).get()` isn't correct (if I'm reading the code correctly).